# Where to report Bintray issues?

Tags: bintray, jcenter

I've got a library that is hosted in JFrog's Bintray (JCenter) and for some reason it's not available to download. I can clearly see that it is available when I go to `https://dl.bintray.com/.../maven/`, I can download files from there, but when I'm trying to include it in my project it cannot resolve.

What is a proper place to report such an issue? I can't see any "issue tracker" in the Bintray's website.

Comment: "All Bintray services will be deprecated and your accounts will be disabled on May 1st 2021" - perhaps what you eperience is part of "We will have some short service brown-outs to remind users about the services that are going away on May 1st."

Comment: Interesting, I'm in the middle of moving to Maven Central, but I didn't expect that before 1st of May there might be some intentional issues. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Actually, I checked an original post and I saw that it mentions that those "brown-outs" should start from 12th April (today), while we are experiencing this issue since last Thursday, so it might be something else.